# Changing values of a variable in a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to merge two tibbles where country names is one of the variables, but they have somewhat different country names in the two tibbles. How can I revalue/replace some country names to make them identical in both tibbles? I have tried different approaches, see code below.

My data is the world map data and data from the world happiness report: https://www.kaggle.com/unsdsn/world-happiness.

```
require(maps)
world_map <- map_data("world")

mapvalues(world_map$order, "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Congo (Kinshasa)")

replace(world_map$order, 32020:32628, 'Congo (Kinshasa)')

recode(world_map$order, "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Congo (Kinshasa)")

revalue(world_map$order, c('Democratic Republic of the Congo' = "Congo (Kinshasa)"))

# This is how I want to merge the tibbles in the end:
happiness_map <- left_join(averages, world_map, by = c("Country" = "region"))
```

Comment: if a straightforward one-to-one mapping for your Country names would exist you could use  `case_when` to replace values: `case_when(Country == "country_name_A" ~ "country_name_B", Country == "country_name_C" ~ "country_name_D", TRUE ~ NA) `

Comment: I receive this error: 
Error: Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a `data.frame` object.
@PaulvanOppen

Comment: Can you share your code please? The `case_when` help text states that the LHS must evaluate to a logical vector. The RHS is the replacement value. The error message suggest that there is some issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I ended up solving it by using the countrycode-package to create a new variable in both tibbles with the iso3c countrycodes, and then joining on iso3c instead. I deleted my old code from the script before I saw your message. Thank you so much for helping, though! Im new to stackexchange. Will provide more code details next time!